# How to stop an action

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to learn C# by creating a simple Windows Form Application.

I have a start button which starts a process inside a while loop when clicked.

I also have a stop button and I would want it to stop the while loop initiated when my start button was clicked.
Problem is, it does not work.
I also have another mechanism which is when I press the Esc button it stops the while loop. This mechanism however works fine.
This is my code:

```cs
class Global
{
    public static string PrcStpr = "off";
    public static string KeyVal;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyPress;
}

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Global.KeyVal = e.KeyCode.ToString();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is my stop button                                                          
{
    Global.PrcStpr = "on";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is my start button
{
    Global.KeyVal = "";
    Global.PrcStpr = "off";
    while (Global.KeyVal != "Escape" || Global.PrcStpr != "on")
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A) you don't get a KeyPress for every button. Details are in the documentation. B.) You only get a KeyPress when the Form has focus not when a control on the form has focus (REad about KeyPreview in the documentation) C.) What is the process you start in the loop. IS it running asynchrounous or also in the mainthread. Typically a thread can only do one thing right calculating something or handling the UI,

Comment: Oh I'm learning, I don't know about asynchronous or else. I'm trying to figure out how I could stop the while loop by clicking another button.

Comment: If you have a loop in an EventHandler you should be _very_ suspicious. EventHandlers should finish _quickly_. If you have a long-running operation, you need to outsource it from the main event handling. Which in modern C# would be: start a CPU-Bound async Task. Those can be stopped using CancellationTokens.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that there is only one UI thread. This means that if the UI thread is doing any kind of processing it cannot do other things, like updating the UI or processing button presses etc.

Your current code does not make much sense to me. I would guess that it will just put a bunch of messages on the message queue, but never get a chance to process them, effectively hanging the application.

So if you need to do something time consuming there are a few possible approaches:

1. Asynchronous processing- This is appropriate if you are doing IO operations, like reading from disk, a database, or marking some webrequest.
2. Background processing - Move the execution to a background thread. This is suitable for compute heavy operations. This should use Tasks to run the code and CancellationToken for cancelling.
3. Timer - Create a timer that runs some piece of code at regular (or non regular) intervals. Timers can run the code either on a background thread or UI thread.

My guess is that you want a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), with an interval of, say 100ms? Put the contents of your loop in an event handler for the Tick-event, and make your buttons set the [Enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property to true/false.

But it is not at all clear what it is you are actually trying to do. Repeatedly setting focus, or using Send Keys like this, seem odd to me. So there is a significant risk that this is a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Oh as I mentioned I'm just trying to learn and experience. I just don't know how to interrupt a while loop initiated by a button with another button or control. I tried to have my "stop" button populating a variable, but it seems my while loop does not care about that. Just learning here really, nothing major.

Comment: @P.MAJ Never put any long running code inside an event handler in a UI program. If it takes longer than say 150ms you should use one of the techniques above instead. For UI programs it is very useful to read a bit about the [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows), since this is at the core the UI.

Comment: Makes sense, many thanks. I also wanted to ask about the likes of a copy paste application then. If you create an app which copies your entire D: drive and paste it in for example an E: drive with press of a button, how then do you pause or cancel it with another button?

Comment: @P.MAJ Copy operations is a form of IO, so you could probably use async calls to do the copying, and a cancellationToken to cancel calls, or cancel between calls. But "copy paste" of files is a OS operation, not part of an application, unless you implement your own copy paste handling.

Comment: So if I created an app using C# which copies files from one folder or drive to next with little knowledge I have, I am out of luck to stop the while loop, right?

Comment: There is no thing that can stop/cancel anything, If you want something to be cancelable you need to write it that way. So if you have written a cancelable copy process then surely you can cancel/stop it. It can contain loops but just because its a loop does not mean anything.

Comment: @P.MAJ All cancellation in c# is *cooperative*, meaning some code needs to periodically check if cancellation is requested and abort. The standard way to do this is with a cancellationToken, Either explicitly by calling throwIfCancellationIsRequested, or to give it to some other method that does it. For example [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=net-7.0#system-io-stream-copytoasync(system-io-stream-system-threading-cancellationtoken))